# Minimize subqueries with IN queries on AppEngine (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gquery

Is there any clever way to avoid making a costly query with an IN clause in cases like the following one?

I'm using Google App Engine to build a Facebook application and at some point I (obviously) need to query the datastore to get all the entities that belong to any of the facebook friends of the given user.

Suppose I have a couple of entities modeled as such:

```
class Thing(db.Model):
    owner = db.ReferenceProperty(reference_class=User, required=True)
    owner_id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    ...
```

and

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    ...
```

At some point I query Facebook to get the list of friends of a given user and I need to perform the following query

```
# get all Thing instances that belong to friends
query = Thing.all()
query.filter('owner_id IN', friend_ids)
```

If I did that, AppEngine would perform a subquery for each id in `friend_ids`, probably exceeding the maximum number of subqueries any query can spawn (30).

Is there any better way to do this (i.e. minimizing the number of queries)?
I understand that there are no relations and joins using the datastore but, in particular, I would consider adding new fields to the `User` or `Thing` class if it helps in making things easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's an elegant solution, but you could try this:

On the User model, use Facebook ID as the key name, and store each user's list of things in a ListProperty.

```
class Thing(db.Model):
  ...

class User(db.Model):
  things = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
  ...
```

Entity creation would go like this:

```
user = User.get_or_insert(my_facebook_id)

thing = Thing()
thing.put()

user.things.append(thing.key())
user.put()
```

Retrieval takes 2 queries:

```
friends = User.get_by_key_name(friend_ids)
thing_keys = []

for friend in friends:
  thing_keys.extend(friend.things)

things = db.get(thing_keys)
```

Comment: +1 Another option is to make Things children to User allows for ancestor queries for a specific type of thing to be returned.  The use of key_names is critical to this really working.

Comment: That's great, I even made Things children to User as suggested by kevpie. I had to deal with a couple more issues, though: a) I don't store a User entity for each friend_id, so I need to filter the None values I get when querying using get_by_key_name; b) I have to filter out things by some other fields as well, but I do that on the entities I fetch after I get them from the DataStore. Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Be sure to watch the talks Nick posted in his answer.  You may want to use an index entity combined with a list property. This is shown in the first talk posted by Nick.

Comment: I'm trying to develop the alternative using index entities. Performing get_by_key_name with a list of Facebook friends as an argument appears to be stressing the DataStore a bit too much. The problem with index entities associated to each user is when to update them to keep them consistent with Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

[This Google I/O talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html) by Brett Slatkin addresses the exact situation you're dealing with. See also [his follow up talk](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/high-throughput-data-pipelines-appengine.html) this year.

Comment: I'm afraid you posted twice the same link to the last talk. Were you referring to this one? http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html